# ViewPager indicator with pictures

Tags: java, android, viewpagerindicator

I want to have ViewPager with photos with the thumbnails at the bottom, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwwKA.png)

I saw some libraries that implements page indicators with dots or something, but I have no idea how to do it with custom different pictures. Also it's need to have an ability to implement animation, as on screenshot selected tab indicator bigger then unselected

The only solution I found is to make another ViewPager for thumbnails, but it must be more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess [this library](https://github.com/VEINHORN/ScrollGalleryView) is the nearest solution for your need.